# Core dump not written on segmentation fault

Tags: linux, kali-linux, core-dump, segmentation-fault

I'm now reading The Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes, 2nd Edition.

In the second chapter considered the simple buffer overflow problem like this (C code):

```
int main () {
    int array[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++ ) {
        array[i] = 10;
    }
}
```

Author compiled the code with `cc` and execute it:

```
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ cc buffer2.c
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

then had a peek at written core dump with `gdb`:

```
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ gdb -q -c core
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x0000000a in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

The problem is that core dump haven't been written in my case. I have only message: `zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out`.

I use Kali 2021.4a in VirtualBox. I have been tried to change default shell with `chsh -s /bin/bash` but it change nothing and terminal keep opens as `zsh`.

How to make core dump written on fault? Looks it's should be file written in the same directory with executable file.

Comment: Please check `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`, e.g. `sudo ls -la /var/lib/systemd/coredump`

Comment: apt install systemd-coredump

Comment: coredumpctl info $MYPID
`coredumpctl gdb $MYPID`

Comment: Check `journalctl` maybe there is information why core dump isn't created. Also check here: https://fromdual.com/hunting-the-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to check the core file size in your limits using `ulimit` command (in bash or in zsh).

```
# ulimit -c
0
```

If it's zero, you need to increase it. For instance, to increase it to unlimited:

```
# ulimit -c unlimited
# ulimit -c          
unlimited
```

Secondly, you need to check where the coredump is created. On older distros, the default was usually a file called "core" in the CWD. That was probably the default when the book was written.

```
# /sbin/sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = core
```

However, today it isn't true anymore on most distros. Today usually the core is generated using [`systemd-coredump(8)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html).

```
# /sbin/sysctl kernel.core_pattern
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %e
```

From man [`systemd-coredump(8)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html):

> By default, systemd-coredump will log the core dump to the journal,
> including a backtrace if possible, and store the core dump (an image
> of the memory contents of the process) itself in an external file in
> **/var/lib/systemd/coredump**.

You can either find the core dump in that directory, or you can use [`coredumpctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/coredumpctl.1.html) to list those (you might require sudo or run it as root):

```
# coredumpctl list
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG PRESENT EXE
Wed 2022-01-26 12:53:06 IST   10347   111   222 11  *       /tmp/a.out
```

The `*` under the "PRESENT" indicates that a core dump file was created.

You could see the location of the (compressed) coredump by using `coredumpctl info <pid>`:

```
# coredumpctl info 10347 |grep Coredump
      Coredump: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.a\x2eout.111.1bd8e22a25e844f1b03a87d378b4ed9b.10347.1643194386000000.xz
```

You can decompress this file using `xz` command:

```
# xz --decompress --stdout '/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.a\x2eout.111.1bd8e22a25e844f1b03a87d378b4ed9b.10347.1643194386000000.xz' > core
```

Or use the following command to dump the core to some destination.

```
# coredumpctl -o core dump 10347
```

Either of those commands will create the file:

```
# gdb -q -c core
[New LWP 10347]
Core was generated by `/tmp/a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000af7a56725 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `man core`, There are various circumstances in which a core dump file is not produced:

> ```
>    *  The process does not have permission to write the core file.…
>
>    *  A (writable, regular) file with the same name as would be used
>       for the core dump already exists, but there is more than one
>       hard link to that file.
>
>    *  The filesystem where the core dump file would be created is
>       full; or has run out of inodes; or is mounted read-only; or
>       the user has reached their quota for the filesystem.
>
>    *  The directory in which the core dump file is to be created
>       does not exist.
>
>    *  The RLIMIT_CORE (core file size) or RLIMIT_FSIZE (file size)
>       resource limits for the process are set to zero;…
>
>    *  The binary being executed by the process does not have read
>       permission enabled.…
>
>    *  The process is executing a set-user-ID (set-group-ID) program
>       that is owned by a user (group) other than the real user
>       (group) ID of the process, or the process is executing a
>       program that has file capabilities…
>
>    *  /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern is empty and
>       /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid contains the value 0.  
>
>    *  (Since Linux 3.7) The kernel was configured without the
>       CONFIG_COREDUMP option.
> ```

So you should first check for these conditions, in particular, the most probable, the last one : **the CONFIG_COREDUMP kernel option**.

BTW, also take note that :

> On systems that employ systemd(1) as the init framework, core dumps
> may instead be placed in a location determined by systemd(1).

which, under many implementations corresponds to some `/var/lib/systemd` subdirectory.